# css animation выполнение одно цикла до конца

Tags: css, анимация

Есть вот такой код:
HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test:hover {animation: rotation 3s linear infinite;}
#test{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    margin: 50px;
}
@keyframes rotation {
    0% {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Вот пример:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxqo6vtn/

При наведении на блок он вращается, но если убрать мышку, он резко возвращается на начальное положение.
Как можно сделать что бы цикл анимации завершался до конца ,если даже мышка уже не на блоке?
Допускаеться использование JS(jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог реализовать на JS, но хотелось бы на CSS.

Вот моё решение:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxqo6vtn/3/

JS:

```
$('#test').mouseover(function(){
    if(!ani) anim();
});
var ani = false;
function anim(){
    ani = true;
    $('#test').animate({
        transform: 180
    },{
        step: function(now, tween) {
            $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
        },
        complete: function(){
            ani = false;
            if($('#test:hover').length>0) anim();
        },
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: 500
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь правило

```
transition: all 3s linear 0s;
```

для блока #test.

Comment: Не чего не поменялось: http://jsfiddle.net/wxqo6vtn/1/

Comment: Почему не поменялось-то? Блок возвращается в исходное положение с анимацией, правда в обратную сторону.

Comment: У меня он резко дёргается в исходное положение